# How to Uninstall Ubuntu server 20.04 on desktop computer

Tags: server

So I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my old Mac Mini, and I've been wanting to change to Ubuntu Desktop instead so if anyone knows how to get Ubuntu Desktop please let me know how uninstall Ubuntu Server and get that OS on there! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu Desktop over another OS (eg. Ubuntu Server), you just install it and it'll overwrite what's there. You don't need to uninstall an OS; you install another over it. You can add `ubuntu-desktop` on top of your existing system too.

Comment: You can run the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`